# swift closure equivalent java lambda

Tags: java, swift

I have to pass this swift closure to a lambda java and java < 8 (in java I have the same method loginUsingPost generate by swagger). 
It's my first time with both languages so I don't know how to handle this.

```
LoginRestControllerAPI.loginUsingPOST(user: user) { (tokenWrapper, error) in
                // code
                completion(auth, nsError)
            }
```

Comment: "lambda java and java < 8" - so you need 2 Java versions one for Java 8+ and one for Java 7-?

Comment: @Thomas Hello thomas, in short term with a lambda should be enough but as it is for an android application if I use java 8 we lose 50% of devices if I'm not wrong.